# Learning Perl, but how do I get 5.14 on Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, perl

So I ordered Learning Perl 6th edition and I know it's using 5.14, but Strawberry Perl is only at 5.12, so what are my options? Is 5.12 fine for it or will there be problems with what's being taught?

Is my only option using Linux? If so distro suggestions would be good along with instructions or a link to instructions on updating perl in said distro (or in general). I'm relatively new to Linux, only ever having installed Ubuntu a few times and never really stuck with it. The perfect solution would be a distro that's good for installing on another PC in my house so I can just remote desktop (or equivalent, even SSH, though GUIs are nice) into since I have an older PC that I want to put a new hard drive in and mess around with. (Pentium 4 with a bit less than a gig of RAM so not awful)

Hopefully this question is considered more constructive than my last two and I look forward to your responses.

Edit: Also any resources for a Linux noob would be a great help if possible and if it's the best option.

Comment: Can't you just use a text-only Linux in a VM ? Something like vmware player or virtualbox.

Comment: As the old saying goes, there are lies, damned lies, and statistics (http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html).  Don't let the curmudgeons try to scare you away from Perl.

Comment: I remember reading Perldelta for 5.14 (http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod) and not noticing many important changes. You should be fine.

Comment: Oh f me. This came up in my RSS feed for a content stealing site and I answered it there. http://programmersgoodies.com/348787/learning-perl-but-how-do-i-get-5-14-on-windows/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't actually seen *Learning Perl* 6th edition, but I would be very surprised if you had difficulty working through it with Perl 5.12.  Perl 5.14 is still too new for most people to be writing code that requires it.  The book may mention some features that you can't take advantage of in 5.12, but it should still explain how to accomplish things using only 5.12 features.

I would recommend just using the current [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and not worrying about the version number.

**Update:** As [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340355/mike) pointed out, here's the opening paragraph of the Preface:

> Welcome to the sixth edition of *Learning Perl*, updated for Perl 5.14 and its latest features.  This book is still good even if you are still using Perl 5.8 (although, it's been a long time since it was released; have you thought about upgrading?).

So that confirms you'll have no problem trying to use 5.12 with the 6th edition.

Comment: I flagged this as the answer since it pretty much answers my question directly. But I am curious about ActivePerl and have asked about it in the comments of those replies.

Comment: Actually, an extremely minimal amount of exercises and code use 5.14 (unless your in Appendix III: Unicode).

Answer (score 8):

I moved from Windows and PHP to Linux and Perl a while ago, and haven't looked back - but I don't want to start an OS or programming language war here.  My desktop is running Ubuntu, but you could stick with Windows (I have Windows available in a VirtualBox VM for those times when I need it).

You can download the Ubuntu Server ISO and attach it as a CD/DVD image via the Virtual Media Manager.  You can then set up as many Ubuntu VMs as you like.  I use very basic setting for mine:

- RAM: 512MB
- Hard Disk: 8GB dynamic
- Network Adapter: Bridged

I have a few images configured.  One is setup with Nginx + Catalyst, one with Bricolage CMS and Apache, and a few other variations (including a PHP one).  The great thing with VMs is that you can create snapshots, duplicate images, experiment, and blow things away and restart if you mess things up.

How you choose to setup your development environment is down to personal choice.  I use [SSHMenu](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/) to open four SSH connections to my development server - this also places the terminals at predefined positions on my screen.

I use one terminal to run code, access the debugger, etc.  I use another for connecting the DBMS client (PostgreSQL / MySQL).  I use the other two for editing code and unit tests.  I use Vim in the terminal as my editor.  I was going to try Emacs too, but never got round to it.

I use git as my version control system, with bare repositories on a separate file server.  I did start with Mercurial, but it appears as though much of the Perl world is using git, so I switched.

I have configured the GNOME terminal to use the beautiful [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) colour scheme (you can find a handy script for that [here](https://github.com/sigurdga/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized)).

As for the Perl version: I don't know.  I agree with other comments about using a standard package rather than trying to build your own - especially if you are a Linux newbie.  I've just looked on the [O'Reilly preview page](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018452/preview#preview), and in the Preface, it says "this book is good even if you are still using Perl 5.8" - so you should be okay with an earlier version.  You also need to be aware that if you are planning on doing web development in Perl, you may be limited to older versions of Perl by your chosen hosting provider.

**A few more thoughts:**

- [Programming Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000271), despite its age, is still a great resource.  One you've completed Learning Perl, and perhaps Intermediate Perl, it's well worth reading.  The section on Pattern Matching (regular expressions) is fantastic.
- [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) is a really good read.  It's well written, concise, and full of really useful tips.
- [cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emiyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.4008/bin/cpanm) is a great alternative to the standard CPAN application.
- [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eapeiron/local-lib-1.008004/lib/local/lib.pm) is very useful.  I use it to create a per-application set of CPAN modules.  This means that I can simply copy the entire directory structure from my development server to the application server, without having to worry about conflicts with other applications that might be using different versions of the same modules.  *This is probably not relevant to you at the moment, but when you've learned more and start using lots of CPAN modules, it can be really handy.*

A quick `local::lib` example:

```
mkdir -p ~/myapp/extlib
cpanm --prompt -L ~/myapp/extlib CPAN::Module1 CPAN::Module2 ...
eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib=~/myapp/extlib/)
```

In `~/myapp/scripts/myscript.pl`:

```
use FindBin;
use local::lib "$FindBin::Bin/../extlib";
```

Comment: The fourth edition of Programming Perl will be published early next year.

Answer (score 8):

## Use ActivePerl

It is a very good product, it is free, and it has a reliable (for the most part) PPM (Perl Package Manager). I use it and have no troubles usually. It is a binary distribution just like Strawberry Perl, but you use PPM to get modules instead of CPAN.pm.

Note: If you are getting Perl 5.14 Just because of the book, don't. I got that book (I am also a beginner) and used 5.12.4. You get mostly all of the features (except for a few ;-)

Comment: What are the main advantages of using ActivePerl over Strawberry besides their timeliness of releases?

Comment: I believe ActivePerl has an easier Module Install

Answer (score 4):

You could

1. Install Windows and then run Ubuntu inside a VM on your Windows machine. You can start it up, ssh to it and then mess around with it.
2. Use [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads).

Comment: +1 for ActivePerl. It contains Perl 5.14 for Windows, both 32 and 64 bit installations.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) - you can download 5.14 or 5.12 and it's as good as Strawberry, even with the complete CPAN toolchain, nowadays. The only limiting factor is the license, it's absolutely free to use but you can't bundle it in any of your apps without getting an OEM license. So for 99% of the cases this is a good distribution.

StrawberryPerl is also suitable, but they usually have a slightly longer delay between the release of a Perl version and the availability of an updated StrawberryPerl version.

Answer (score 1):

I have a fully updated Ubuntu 11.04; it has Perl 5.10.1.  I don't know how up to date other Linux distributions are.  Cygwin also has 5.10.1.

You could always build from source.

Comment: My Fedora 15 comes with 5.12.4.

Comment: Building from source really is not as nice as getting a compiled version. Sure, it's possible, but you'll need to install a compiler, it takes lots of time and if you want to use for instance DBD::mysql you'll need those header files as well. It's tedious, especially if your objective is to write "say "Hello World";".

Comment: @MichielB: Sure, but it might be the only option if the latest version isn't available precompiled for your platform.

Comment: On Windows, it is available in precompiled form and you should absolutely go with that. On Linux systems, compiling is not as tedious as on windows, and App::perlbrew is a very nice helper for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can either use Active Perl, or use a GNU/Linux distro and get the latest Perl from it's repos. GNU/Linux is not Windows, it is open-source and you can install it on as many PCs as you want it. You could try Ubuntu or it's builds for an easy-to-use system.

Answer (score 1):

Most of *Learning Perl* doesn't depend on Perl 5.14 features, and those that do are clearly marked. In most cases, I try to show a non-v5.14 way to do the same thing. You'll miss out on some nice v5.14 features, but you won't be stuck without them. And, for what it is worth, the new *Programming Perl*, due very soon, covers up to v5.16. Don't buy the old version if you don't have it yet.

Many people have already suggested very good options for various Perls, so I won't repeat those. My advice to students is always to learn on the Perl version and operating system you want to deploy to.

You don't have to stick to Windows. You can get a virtual machine of just about any operating system you like. [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) and [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) have free players and many places offer pre-configured virtual machines. From there, you can install any Perl version that you like. It's also incredibly cheap and easy to have multi-boot systems (although a VM doesn't prevent you from using both at the same time).

On Windows, you can also install cygwin, then install any Perl that you like.

Also, there is a [preview release for Strawberry Perl 5.14](http://strawberryperl.com/beta/index.html).